# To get a function which returns an array of all possible combinations of m numbers in n numbers

Tags: c

Given n consecutive numbers, starting from 0. How do I get all the combinations of m numbers from n?
For example:

```
n = 5, m = 2  
given numbers: 0,1,2,3,4  
expected output: return an array, where arr[][] = {{0,1},{0,2},...,{3,4}}
```

And n and m are not constants.

```
int **getSource(int nV, int num){
    int c = num_of_com(nV, num);
    int **source = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*c);
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
            source[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
            for(int j=nV;j>=num;j--){
                *(*(source+i)+num-1)=j-2;
                if(num>1)
                getSource(nV-1,num-1);
            }
        }
        
    return source;
}
```

I wrote this and it didn't succeed.

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Consider making the arrays implicit, and representing them using bit masks instead. If `m` is larger than the integer types, then arrays of unsigned integers to hold all the bits  are quite easy to manage. I don't understand the relevance of the code in the question at all.

Comment: Why do you call the `getSource` fuction recursively if `num > 1`?

Comment: I would create an array of size `m`, and initialize it with the first combination. So for example, with `n=5` and `m=2`, it would be `int combo[] = { 0, 1 };`. Then in a loop, print the current combo, and then update the combo array. That can be done iteratively, no recursion is required.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of the algorithm. "get all the combinations of m numbers from n?"  ... "n = 5, m = 2 given numbers: 0,1,2,3,4 expected outout"  What does that even mean? Are you to generate a matrix of 5x2 then fill it with all possible permutations of 0 to (n-1) or what? Because that's not what you said. Where did 0,1,2,3,4 come from?

Comment: Note that this problem can be read as: provide all numbers in base-*n* from *0* to *n^m* where every digit is smaller than its next digit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of a recursive solution. The core function is 'pick'. The idea is to mark in an array if the number at position 'i' in the array should be picked or not. The length of the array is what you call 'n', so at most 'm' elements in the array should get picked. At the bottom of the recursion the array gets printed, only printing whose elements that are selected.

The parameters should of course be supplied on the command line, and the array should be passed as an argument to the recursive function.

I have tested with n = 5 and m = 2. It may not work for other combinations. But it may inspire you anyway :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool *current;

static int n = 5;
static int m = 3;

static void print_current(void)
{
  printf("{ ");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (current[i])
        {
          printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
  printf("}\n");
}

static void pick(int candidate, int n, int m)
{
  if (m == 0)
    {
      print_current();
    }
  else if (candidate < n)
    {
      current[candidate] = true;
      pick(candidate+1, n, m - 1);
      current[candidate] = false;
      pick(candidate+1, n, m);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  
  printf("Hello\n");
  
  current = malloc(n*sizeof(bool));
  memset(current, false, n);
  pick(0, n, m);
  free(current);
  return 0;
}
```

Update: Output for n = 5 and m = 3:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the output of the program?